# Run Rstudio from a particular docker image

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

Question: How can I run rstudio locally from a particular docker image?

---

I'm aware that `rocker` provides an image which can be used as `docker run -e PASSWORD=yourpassword --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/rstudio`, but I would like to be able use this functionality with a custom image.

I have the following, sorry if this could be reduced further - I didn't want to lose any important context:

```
from rocker/r-bspm:20.04

RUN apt update -qq 

# setup C++ Bits needed for working with Stan stuff.
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+
RUN apt-get update

# Install rstan.
RUN install.r rstan
# Need this in order to install specific versions of R packages.
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'

# I'm following the outlines here for the following: 
# https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/#installation
RUN R -e 'install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))'
RUN R -e "cmdstanr::install_cmdstan()"

# Install rethinking package.
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("coda","mvtnorm","devtools","loo","dagitty","shape"))'
RUN R -e 'devtools::install_github("rmcelreath/rethinking")'

# Install Rstudio - From here is what I've added to the image in order to 
# try and use Rstudio from this image.
RUN apt -y install r-base gdebi-core
RUN wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb
RUN gdebi -n rstudio-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb
```

After building this image with:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t r_stat .
```

I attempted to just copy the `rocker` command as follows:

```
docker run -e PASSWORD=password --rm -p 8787:8787 r_stat
```

This didn't seem to do anything though, and going to `localhost:8787` in the browser didn't bring anything up.

Comment: Maybe you may want to use Not  Rstudio desktop but Rstudio server.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 if i can install it in a dockerfile like that in the post, and launch it like i can with the `rocker/rstudio` command at the top of the post, then I think that is what I'd like. Thanks

Comment: you have to add CMD ["R"] at the end line of the dockerfile and then rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM rocker/r-bspm:20.04

RUN apt update -qq 

# setup C++ Bits needed for working with Stan stuff.
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+
RUN apt-get update

# Install rstan.
RUN install.r rstan
# Need this in order to install specific versions of R packages.
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'

# I'm following the outlines here for the following: 
# https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/#installation
RUN R -e 'install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))'
RUN R -e "cmdstanr::install_cmdstan()"

# Install rethinking package.
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("coda","mvtnorm","devtools","loo","dagitty","shape"))'
RUN R -e 'devtools::install_github("rmcelreath/rethinking")'

# Install Rstudio - From here is what I've added to the image in order to 
# try and use Rstudio from this image.
RUN apt -y install r-base gdebi-core
RUN wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb
RUN gdebi -n rstudio-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb

CMD ["R"]
```

And then rebuild it.